# java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1- connection is not available

Tags: java

I am a newbie assigned to build a hostel management application using HikariPool connection. Now, i sometimes get this error `java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1- connection is not available` and once it happens, it messes up my application data. For  instance, in my code below, i call the function  `paymentRecord()` in my `AssignRoom()` to execute after a room is assigned.

I open and close connections in each functions(AssignRoom() and paymentRecord()) but sometimes, one of the functions fail to execute. It is either AssignRoom() executes correctly and paymentRecord() fails to execute or vice versa.

My code may be very bad but i am newbie trying to learn.

**PS:** Now i never had this issue when i was testing the application with good internet connection , but my Client did report this and he mostly has internet connectivity problem.

I sometimes think the internet connection might be a factor to my problem, if so why do i deal with this please?

**Assigning Room**

```
 public void AssignRoom(){
        try
        {
          java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(date.getDate().getTime());

            conn = DBConnection.getConn();
            String query = "Insert into AssignRoom(Floor,RoomNumber,Student,DateAssigned) values (?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, Floor.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setString(2, FindRoom.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setString(3, FindStd.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setDate(4, sqldate);

            pst.execute();
            if(seats.getText().equals("0")){

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Room is fully occupied");
                }
            else 
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Room Successfully Assigned");
                     UpdateAvailableBeds();
                   paymentRecord();


                     conn.close();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please wait...Processing payment");
                    navToPayment();  
            }


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Payment Record**

```
public void paymentRecord()
    {

        try
        {
            java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(date.getDate().getTime());
            System.out.println("Cheking "+sqldate);
            System.out.println("Cheking "+FindRoom.getSelectedItem().toString());
            System.out.println("Cheking "+FindStd.getSelectedItem().toString());





            conn = DBConnection.getConn();

            String query = "Insert into PaymentRecords(Student_Name,Room_Number,DateAssigned,Total_Amount,Paid,Balance) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            String sql = "select Price from Rooms where RoomNumber =" +FindRoom.getSelectedItem()+ " and Floor ='"+Floor.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";

            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           // ResultSet rs = pst.executeUpdate(query);
            ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs1.next())
            {
             FullAmount = rs1.getString("Price");

              Price = Float.parseFloat(FullAmount);
              Rem = Float.parseFloat(AmtPaid.getText());
              Balance = Price - Rem;

              System.out.println("Cheking "+FullAmount);

            }
            pst.setString(1, FindStd.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setString(2, FindRoom.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setDate(3, sqldate);
            pst.setString(4, FullAmount);
            pst.setString(5, AmtPaid.getText());
            pst.setFloat(6, Balance);




            pst.execute();
            pst1.execute();
           conn.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to handle the exception better, rather than showing it on screen?

Comment: @Assafs, yeah probably handle the exception better. Because when the exception occurs . It is either AssignRoom() executes correctly and paymentRecord() fails to execute or vice versa. This messes up the data

Comment: If you had to describe a list of instructions - without worrying about coding them for now - on what to do if an exception happens, what would those be?

Comment: @Assafs  Your question isn't really clear to me. I am trying to find out if internet connectivity can sought of create this problem as described in the S.O question

Comment: Unfortunately, if this question is related to the cause of the exceptions - something about your network, let's say - then I can't help you. Networking questions are not my specialty, and are not the topic that StackOverflow deals with in general. I could help you recover from them by having some exception handling in your code.